# Rails link_to not linking to absolute file path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, actionview

My code is

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(image_path, :border => "0"), images_display_url(id: image.id))  %>
```

Where image_path has the value of `/Users/me/rails/image_uploader/public/images/thumbnail-78b8672302481b652092d4232f66e.jpg`

Why is it not displaying any image I link in it? All it shows is that broken thumbnail icon. When I go to the link in my browser it loads the correct image.

Answer (score 0):

you can try do parse it as a block

```
<%= link_to do 
    image_tag images_display_url(id: image.id), image_path, html => {:border => "0"}
end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

[link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) also accepts a block as argument

```
<%= link_to image_path do 
    image_tag images_display_url(id: image.id), html = {:border => "0"}
end %>
```